# What does "?\s" mean in Elixir?

Tags: string, char, elixir

In the Elixir-documentation covering [comprehensions](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html) I ran across the following example:

```erlang
iex> for <<c <- " hello world ">>, c != ?\s, into: "", do: <<c>>
"helloworld"
```

I sort of understand the whole expression now, but I can't figure out what the "?\s" means. 
I know that it somehow matches and thus filters out the spaces, but that's where my understanding ends.

Edit: I have now figured out that it resolves to 32, which is the character code of a space, but I still don't know why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) has char literals denoted by a dollar sign.

```erlang
Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.6.1] [...]

Eshell V10.6.1  (abort with ^G)
1> $\s == 32.
%%⇒ true
```

The same way [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) has char literals that according to the [code documentation](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/src/elixir_tokenizer.erl#L227-L236) act exactly as *erlang* char literals:

> This is exactly what Erlang does with Erlang char literals ($a).

---

Basically, `?\s` is exactly the same as `?`  (question mark followed by a space.)

```rb
#               ⇓ space here
iex|1 ▶ ?\s == ? 
warning: found ? followed by code point 0x20 (space), please use ?\s instead
```

There is nothing special with `?\s`, as you might see:

```rb
for <<c <- " hello world ">>, c != ?o, into: "", do: <<c>> 
#⇒ " hell wrld "
```

Also, [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) as well uses `?c` notation for char literals:

```rb
main> ?\s == ' '
#⇒ true
```

Answer (score 3):

`?` is a literal that gives you the following character's codepoint( https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html#utf-8-and-unicode). For characters that cannot be expressed literally (space is just one of them, but there are more: tab, carriage return, ...) the escaped sequence should be used instead. So `?\s` gives you a codepoint for space:

```
iex> ?\s
32
```